# How checked checkboxes remember on all pages in wp_list_table pagination?

Tags: pagination

I am working on a plugin in which I am using wp_list_table and displaying post and pages.

I am facing a issue like I m using pagination and have almost 20 pages, I select a post or page (using checkboxe) on page 1 and another post or page on pagination page 5,when I try to get all selected posts or pages it only show current page selected post or page.

Please any suggestion?

Thanks in advance.

Ashikra

Comment: It's normal behavior of checkboxes. When you click on the previous/next page, your browser refreshes everything that are not store in cookies and sessions.

Comment: You can use cookies, session variables, post/get variables, .....

Comment: Hi cybmeta & Dan thanks for your response.Please any code idea how I can achived it ?please...